# Java 8 Optional, multiple filter and multiple map

Tags: java, java-8

I would like to use Java 8, how can I make this imperative style to functional style in java 8 [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) ?

For instance, let's say **exchange.getIn().getBody()** maybe null or not.

```
String color = null;
if(exchange.getIn().getBody() instanceof Foo) {
    color = "toFoo";
} else if(exchange.getIn().getBody() instanceof Bar){
    color = "toBar";
}
```

Maybe something thing like this, but I need it to be in one liner.

```
 Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getIn().getBody())
         .filter(body -> body instanceof Foo)
         .map(body ->  "toFoo");
```

My problem is that map already a String, so I was not able to make it one liner:

```
 Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getIn().getBody())
         .filter(body -> body instanceof Foo)
         .map(body ->  "toFoo")
         .orElse(exchange.getIn().getBody()) //this part is problem, already String
         .filter(body -> body instanceof Bar)
         .map(body -> "toBar");
```

Comment: `color = "to"+exchange.getIn().getBody().getClass().getSimpleName();`

Comment: I don't understand how this code relates to `Optional`, filter and/or map operations.

Comment: Don't do that. Add a method `getColor()` to the return type of `getBody()` that returns the correct color. Then you can refactor your code to `String color = exchange.getIn().getBody().getColor();` and avoid the need of `instanceof`.

Comment: Can you make `Foo` and `Bar` implement a common interface?

Comment: I can't make a common interface for them, let's say they are completely different domain.

Comment: Then I think you should probably stick with your `if` statement.

Comment: If you stick to your `instanceof` tests, the you should store the result of `exchange.getIn().getBody()` in a local variable instead of having that expression twice in your code. Besides that, the fact that the result can be `null` is irrelevant. `instanceof` already handles `null` references well.

Comment: I am just exploring Java 8 functional style, I thought it can support scenario like this.

Comment: The idea is not about how the instanceof behave, the idea is already in the post title, how to use **map** in which depends on multiple **filter**

Comment: what you really want is [pattern matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html), java does not offer that out of the box. Imo it's an abuse of optionals what you're doing. That said, java 9 will have an [Optional.or](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-) that would work for your approach. also `Foo.class::isInstance` may be slightly more concise for type checks in lambdas

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is pattern matching, which is not what `Optional` is for. You can abuse `Optional` to get something that produces the desired result, e.g.

```
Object o=exchange.getIn().getBody();
String color=Optional.ofNullable(o).filter(Foo.class::isInstance).map(x->"toFoo")
    .orElseGet(()->Optional.ofNullable(o).filter(Bar.class::isInstance).map(x->"toBar")
    .orElse("fallback"));
```

but that’s obviously not a real win, especially if you consider what will happen, when you add more cases.

One way to achieve your goal is to associate predicates and results via a `Map`:

```
Map<Predicate<Object>,String> alternatives=new HashMap<>();
alternatives.put(Bar.class::isInstance, "toBar");
alternatives.put(Foo.class::isInstance, "toFoo");

Object o=exchange.getIn().getBody();
String color=alternatives.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e->e.getKey().test(o))
    .findAny().map(Map.Entry::getValue).orElse("fallback");
```

This performs a linear search (in no particular order so the predicates must be disjunct), which works well for a small number of cases, and you can add another case as simple as

```
alternatives.put(Baz.class::isInstance, "toBaz");
```

but for larger number of cases, encoding the predicate in a way that allows an efficient lookup (e.g. using classes as map keys and adding encountered subclasses dynamically) is preferable.

Note that the two examples above use `"fallback"` as value for the case that no predicate is fulfilled. You may simply replace it with `null` to get the same fallback result as in your question’s code.

Answer (score 1):

To get your one-liner, I would "turn around" the logic to something like:

```
Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody();
Stream.of(
  new Pair<Class, String>(Foo.class, "toFoo"), 
  new Pair<Class, String>(Bar.class, "toBar"))
      .filter(pair -> body != null && body.getClass().isAssignableFrom(pair.getKey())))
      .findFirst()
      .map(Pair::getValue)
      .orElse("default");
```

;

Comment: Instead of `Arrays.asList(a, b).stream()` you can simply use `Stream.of(a, b)`. And you should decide whether your variable is named `color` or `result`, but there is no need to modify a `StringBuilder` at all, you can simply use `.map(Pair::getValue).orElse(…)` instead of `ifPresent`.